# Javacript fuctionality to switch between Login & Create Account on sign up form not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a sign-in/create account form using HTML/CSS/Javascript. I've written the HTML code and styled the forms, however, I'm unable to get the link at the bottom of the form "Already have an account? Sign in" to switch to the 'Sign In' form.

Here is the code.

Any guidance on helping me pin-point the issue is always appreciated.

Sean

Here is what i've tried so-far

```js
function setFormMessage(formElement, type, message) {
  const messageElement = formElement.querySelector(".form__message");

  messageElement.textContent = message;
  messageElement.classList.remove("form__message--success", "form__message--error");
  messageElement.classList.add(`form__message--${type}`);
}

function setInputError(inputElement, message) {
  inputElement.classList.add("form__input--error");
  inputElement.parentElement.querySelector(".form__input-error-message").textContent = message;
}

function clearInputError(inputElement) {
  inputElement.classList.remove("form__input--error");
  inputElement.parentElement.querySelector(".form__input-error-message").textContent = "";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login");
  const createAccountForm = document.querySelector("#createAccount");

  document.querySelector("#linkCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
    createAccountForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
  });

  document.querySelector("#linkLogin").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
    createAccountForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
  });

  loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Perform your AJAX/Fetch login

    setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "Invalid username/password combination");
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".form__input").forEach(inputElement => {
    inputElement.addEventListener("blur", e => {
      if (e.target.id === "signupUsername" && e.target.value.length > 0 && e.target.value.length < 10) {
        setInputError(inputElement, "Username must be at least 10 characters in length");
      }
    });

    inputElement.addEventListener("input", e => {
      clearInputError(inputElement);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login / Signup Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form form--hidden" id="loginForm">
        <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
        <div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
        <div class="form__input-group"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username or email">
        <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
        <div class="form__input-group">
          <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
          <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
        <p class="form__text">
          <a href="#" class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
        </p>
        <p class="form__text">
          <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
        </p>
      </form>
      <form class="form" id="createAccountForm">
        <h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1>
        <div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
        <div class="form__input-group"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username">
        <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
        <div class="form__input-group"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Email Address">
        <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
        <div class="form__input-group">
          <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
          <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
          <div class="form__input-group">
            <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Confirm Password">
            <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
          </div>
          <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
          <p class="form__text">
            <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
          </p>
      </form>
      </div>
      <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no `id="login"` in the HTML, so `loginForm` is null.

Comment: It should be `const loginForm = document.querySelector("#loginForm");` not `const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login");`

Comment: And the same with `createAccountForm`

Comment: These caused errors in the console, didn't you see them when you were trying to debug your code?

Comment: In all honesty, no it wasn't highlighted when debugging the code but to be fair I know very little at the moment, both about the code and about the VS Code editor I'm using. 
Changing the id "login" to id "logInForm" and the same for the "createAccount" changed to "createAccountForm" has fixed the issue. 
I do really appreciate the help, thanks